# Error al recorrer con forEach

Tags: javascript

***Por qué me dice que forEach no es una función?***

*Lo que hago es obtener los elementos con clase 'clases' y luego asignarle a cada uno un evento onclick, **pero no me FUNCIONA***

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 
 var i = document.getElementsByClassName('clases');
 i.forEach(e => {
 e.onclick = () => {alert('BonApetit');};
 });
 
});
```

```html
<a class="clases">Enlace 1</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 2</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 3</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 4</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que `document.getElementsByClassName` no devuelve un `Array`, sino un objeto [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) que, aunque es muy similar a un array, no tiene ninguna de las funciones que la clase `Array` tiene para recorrer los elementos.

Una solución sería "robar" a `Array` la función `forEach` para usarla sobre este objeto:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 
 var i = document.getElementsByClassName('clases');
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(i,e => {
 e.onclick = () => {alert('BonApetit');};
 });
 
});
```

```html
<a class="clases">Enlace 1</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 2</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 3</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 4</a>
```

Lo que hace este código es ejecutar el método `forEach` de `Array`, pero asignando `i` como contexto (el `this` dentro de esa función)

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que `getElementsByClassName` no devuelve un objeto `Array` si no un `HTMLCollection` que no tiene el método `forEach`:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 
 var i = document.getElementsByClassName('clases');
 for(var cont=0; cont < i.length; cont++){
  i.item(cont).onclick = () => {alert('BonApetit');};
 } 
});
```

```html
<a class="clases">Enlace 1</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 2</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 3</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 4</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como te han comentado arriba, no puedes tratar al objeto como array, pero si puedes extraer del objeto los datos para guardarlos en uno.

**Array.from()**

*El método Array.from() crea una nueva instancia de Array a partir de un objeto iterable.*

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 
 var i = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('clases'));
 i.forEach(e => {
 e.onclick = () => {alert('BonApetit');};
 });
 
});
```

```html
<a class="clases">Enlace 1</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 2</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 3</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 4</a>
```

Te dejo aqui un [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from) a la docu.

Comment: Otra buena opción, probablemente más general que la mía

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 
 var i = document.getElementsByClassName('clases');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(i, function(elements, index) {
    elements.onclick = () => {alert('BonApetit');};
});
});
```

```html
<a class="clases">Enlace 1</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 2</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 3</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 4</a>
```